# Can you write a concept for ContiguousIterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++-concepts, c++20

I know there is concept for ContiguousIterator in [words specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ContiguousIterator) sense, but I wonder if it can be written using C++20/C++17 Concepts TS syntax.

My problem with this is that unlike [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) ContiguousIterator  requires not just some operations like `it+123` to work, but depends on runtime result of that operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot, not without a traits class or other helper, where types opt-in to being contiguous.

Comment: I don't know... isn't the definition for some `ContiguousIterator i` that `&*(i+1) == &*i + 1`??

Comment: @massa How do you check that at compile time?  Over all instances of the type?

Comment: I don't have an answer, and I have to concede that it may be impossible... If I can grasp it, I'll come back here :-/

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is currently unsolvable. The committee is considering what to do about deducing contiguous memory access. The flub is that iterator_category is not a trait (although it resides in iterator_traits); It is an ad-hoc type. It cannot be subtyped without breaking existing code. (Beginner mistake, eh what?) The Committee has recognized the mess.  This recent discussion tells all -> [How to deduce contiguous memory from iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642228/how-to-deduce-contiguous-memory-from-iterator)