# Implementing std::iter_­difference_­t

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm implementing my own version of ranges because they are not in the standard library yet. I got stuck on implementing `std::iter_­difference_­t`.

The [latest draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/incrementable.traits#2) says:

> The type `iter_­difference_­t<I>` denotes
>
> `incrementable_­traits<I>​::​difference_­type` if `iterator_­traits<I>` names a specialization generated from the primary template, and
>
> `iterator_­traits<I>​::​​difference_­type` otherwise.

It seems like the obvious implementation is to have a concept for the first case and have 2nd case take everything else. But I have no idea how to transform this from English to C++. Can someone provide the code?

Comment: *"my own version of ranges because they are not in the standard library yet"* Have you considered [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)?

Comment: The first case is not implementable if you don't own `iterator_traits`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1. Be the owner of `std::iterator_traits`. This lets you write something in the primary like:

```
template <typename T>
struct iterator_traits {
    using __secret_am_i_the_primary_alias = iterator_traits;
};
```

Which you can check:

```
template <typename T>
concept is_iterator_primary = std::same_as<
    typename iterator_traits<T>::__secret_am_i_the_primary_alias,
    iterator_traits<T>>;
```

Step 2. Now it's pretty easy:

```
template <typename T>
struct iter_difference {
    using type = typename iterator_­traits<I>​::​​difference_­type;
};

template <is_iterator_primary T>
struct iter_difference<T> {
    using type = typename incrementable_­traits<I>​::​difference_­type;
};

template <typename T>
using iter_difference_t = typename iter_difference<T>::type;
```

Comment: Nitpick:`template<class T> using iter_difference_t = typename conditional_t<is_iterator_primary<T>, incrementable_traits<T>, iterator_traits<T>>::difference_type;` is a bit more compact for Step 2.